# Why did pandas format my datetime 1999-12-02 19:30:00+00:00

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have data in a CSV with a Date_Time column containing datetime in this format: 1999-12-02T19:30:00Z.  This shows when data was sampled by a weather sensor.  Using Pandas, I'd like to convert the timestamps into a format I could use to resample the data later.

I read in the CSV into a data frame.  Then I converting the original Date_Time column to Pandas datetime using pd.to_datetime, but ended up with an extra +00:00 after every timestamp.

```
df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'])
```

I was expecting to get 1999-12-02 19:30 but got 1999-12-02 19:30:00+00:00 instead.  I've run into issues when trying to resample, and want to resolve this issue first to see if it's the problem.

Comment: Your original datetime data have timezone ?

Comment: did u try to get the proper `format=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just format it:

```
df['Date_Time1'] = df['Date_Time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Comment: Just remember the column is now no longer a timestamp, it is again a string.

Answer (score 2):

The Z in the original time stamp means ‘zero hour offset’ or UTC time. Which seems to be shown in your pandas dataframe as +00:00

You could try removing the time zone

```
df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'].df.tz_localize(None))
```

Comment: Thanks for revealing the root of the issue!

Comment: I just updated my answer, should slow you too keep it as a time stamp and not convert it to string like the answer above